# Understanding velodyne transform_node vs cloud_node to transform point clouds

Tags: ros, velodyne-pointcloud, velodyne-driver, velodyne, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

I was looking into the source code for the velodyne package and I've a couple of questions about `cloud_node` and `transform_node` which I'm hoping to learn more about.

Consider the following cases:

**Case 1:** I use the `cloud_node` to get point clouds  in the 'velodyne' frame. Given the `velodyne->odom` transform exists, I can use tf to transform the point clouds to the `odom` frame.

**Case 2:** I use the `transform_node`,  `VelodynePackets` are unpacked into point clouds and transform for
`velodyne->odom` is applied within the node (from line 111 in transform.cc)

```
pcl_ros::transformPointCloud(inPc_.header.frame_id,
                                     ros::Time(0), inPc_,
                                     config_.frame_id,
                                     tfPc_, listener_);
```

Here's my question: Is there any advantage to transforming point clouds from individual `VelodynePackets` (in Case 2), as opposed to the full point cloud (Case 1)? When would I use one over the other?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/235705/understanding-velodyne-transform_node-vs-cloud_node-to-transform-point-clouds/) by [Venkat Ganesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26837/venkat-ganesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 57 on 2016-05-31

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The main use of `transform_node` is when the device is moving fast enough for the transforms to change significantly during the 0.1 second required for a full revolution (assuming 600 RPM). This is especially important if the heading changes.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2016-06-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1